# Query + importrange not providing the answer i need

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I am attempting to get some information from a [Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1er6drwogbR3-MAAYrtz96V1i_Cs0jTngcGYUeZ10rmA/edit#gid=1418684261)

Basically if my website Id was to be lets say 14, I'd want to get the name in the row next to it;

I am using the function below;

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1er6drwogbR3-MAAYrtz96V1i_Cs0jTngcGYUeZ10rmA/edit#gid=1418684261", "A:Z"), "SELECT Col4 where Col5='14'")`

My expected output would be 'Chad G' But I am getting 'Name' instead...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Col5` has numbers but you are comparing it to a text value. Instead of  `Col5='14'` use  `Col5=14`

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1er6drwogbR3-MAAYrtz96V1i_Cs0jTngcGYUeZ10rmA/edit#gid=1418684261", "A:Z"), "SELECT Col4 where Col5=14")`